# Enhance reading speed from event log?

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, event-log

I have an application reading some data from the event log, this application performance is too bad if the event log was too large, i.e. more than 30,000 entry.

I am searching for a faster way to get the info from it,

I have used for now two ways, using WMI the query was {Select message from Win32_NTLogEvent Where Logfile = 'System' and EventCode = '1' }

I used System.Diagnostic.Eventlog.GetEventLogs(); which also takes too much time

What should I use to enhance the search speed?

Comment: have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411384/which-approach-is-better-to-read-windows-event-log-in-c-wmi-or-eventlog

Comment: @Giedrius , Thanks for replying, I tried it, but it do not bring all the information I need, I need at least the record ID and the event ID and the message

Comment: Can you please post a time needed for your program to execute on 30,000 events in eventlog?

Comment: on core i5 it took about 15 second

Comment: Regarding @Giedrius' suggestion: the `EventLogReader` returns an `EventLogRecord`, which contains both the fields you mention.

Comment: @Christian.K yes, you are right, I did not notice that, Thanks a lot. I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple piece of code takes 4.6 seconds on 100,000 events on AMD Athlon X3 (i5 is more faster).

```
string queryString = "*";
int eventsCount = 0;
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
EventLogQuery eventsQuery = new EventLogQuery("MyLog", PathType.LogName, queryString);
EventLogReader logReader = new EventLogReader(eventsQuery);

for (EventRecord eventInstance = logReader.ReadEvent();
                null != eventInstance; eventInstance = logReader.ReadEvent())
{
  if (eventInstance.Id == 100) //random event id                 
     ++eventsCount;

}
stopWatch.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("Found events: {0}", eventsCount);
Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", stopWatch.Elapsed);
```

For better performance you can use a properly created XPATH Query, by your own or via windows eventviewer (create `Custom view` than choose `XML` tab)

Comment: This way helped me saving some seconds, for example, one PCs with the old way needed 21 seconds to perform the search needed, but using your way it became 15 seconds, still I need a faster way, but I assume there is not, :)\

Comment: @AbdallahNasir actually, you can do some multithreading programming ;) For example, separate log reading in several threads, first thread reading first 0 - 4999 events, second reading events from 5000 to 9999 events, etc.

Comment: I have not thought about that, since I have not done something similar yet, Thanks :)